# JQuery - how to store each data received

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

how to store data received from below Jquery for further use.

```
$('#div').find('a').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mvm6o208/ you can find my code here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make an array and push values to it. Like

```
var store = [];
$('#div').find('a').each(function() {
    store.push($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Update : According to the html in the fiddle you have posted, the selector should be  `$('div').find('a')` instead of `$('#div').find('a')`, as you dont have any div with id `div`. See a working [**fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mvm6o208/2/).

Also as per [the inputs](http://jsperf.com/index-vs-push/17) from comments below, it would be faster approach to push to an array via

```
store[store.length] = $(this).attr('href');
```

Comment: Why do all like `$('#div').find('a')` much more than `$('#div a')`?

Comment: @Regent Because `$('#div a')` will execute in a similar way as `$('#div').find('a')`.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh instead of `store.push([...]);` you should use `store[store.length]=[...];`

Comment: @Satpal Nothing, besides the slight speed increase. (Don't overlook a few cycles on your cpu: those are precious)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel : dont know if your suggestion has a performance benefit. But surely the push version is more readable. :)

Comment: @mithunsatheesh It has. Depending on the engine. Check here: http://jsperf.com/index-vs-push/17

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel : thanks for the link. makes sense now. :)

Comment: @Regent It really is shorter. Can't deny that. And it's true that it might hurt a bit of readability but for people like me (that never remember the function names and what for those are), using `store[store.length]=[...];` is a lot easier to remember.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh Related to the link, most of the times the method using `arr.length` is faster than the one using `arr.push()` (At least for webkit and blink engines, which are the most used so far, as far as I know). So, it would be nice if you added that option with the provided link too.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel : no problems brother. added it. thanks to you. :)

Comment: @mithunsatheesh Just one thing: since the attribute `href` is mapped to the HTML property (any changes on one of those will change both), and you can access it directly in a cross-browser way without trouble, one could use `this.href||''` instead. And thanks for the edit, I just checked it now.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel : I tried to take his code and make it working with minimal alterations. That was the attempt. :). I believe he is in a learning stage and its better not to confuse him with micro optimizations.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh I would disagree about it being "micro optimizations", since it has a big impact in the performance. Using a "heavy" library to only take a single property and rebuilding it every time you need to access a new object, seems hugely wasteful for me. This is just another suggestion, which should be noticed. There are things that jQuery makes easy (animations, events, css settings, etc.) and others that is simply a waste to use. I agree with the part to do not confuse, I disagree about you calling a micro optimization.

Answer (score 1):

```
var refsArray = $('#div').find('a').map(function(item) {
    return $(item).attr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting a div and not a thing like this id="div", so you just need to remove the # :

```
$('div').find('a').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```